# Where can we open the `Post-build script` box of a build process template?

Tags: tfs, build-process, post-build-event, run-script

As guided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx#scripts), we can add extra script to run along the build process.

I can't find where to open this dialog to put my script in the post-build box.

Where is it?

*Update*

I go for `Edit a build definition` - Process section and just see the below properties.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Right click on your build definition and select edit. Once in that screen select option "Process" on the left and then expand the Advanced section and you should find it there.

[image]

Comment: I go for that but cannot find it. I have updated my OP to relect this.

Comment: Looks like you are using the default template. You need to use TfvcTemplate.12.xaml template. I have updated the answer with the screenshot.

Comment: Is the template from TFS 2013? I'm using TFS 2012

Comment: Yes probably not available in TFS 2012... You can download the template from below location. Try to import it and see if it works. It might not work though. You can also try copying that part to your template and see if that works.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1hllqad2TIKNkM4MVE4WHdkdk0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Post-build script path` depends entirely on the **Build process template** you're using.  Some templates have this option, others don't.

I recommend using the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml mentioned by @adarsh-shaw in his answer.  *(Look at the nice screenshot he included in his answer)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a `post-build event`, then you can do it by right clicking on the Project and going to Properties. The is a `Build Events` tab on the left hand side. You can write pre-build and post-build events in the relevant editors.

Comment: TFS specific question